# How to define a type that would allow an object key or value

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of constants grouped in objects, but I can't get the typings right. I'd like to be able to use either a string or by passing in the object property by accessing through the object.

What I would like:

```
export const ACTIONS = {
    SOMETHING: 'SOMETHING',
    // ...
}

export function example(keyOrValue:  SomeTypeDefThatWorks) {
    // ...
}

example('SOMETHING') // valid
example(ACTIONS.SOMETHING) // valid
example('') // invalid
```

My attempts so far:

```
export const ACTIONS = {
    SOMETHING: 'SOMETHING',
}

export type ActionsType = typeof ACTIONS
export type ActionValues = ActionsType[keyof ActionsType]

export function example1(keyOrValue:  keyof ActionsType) {
    // ...
}
example1('') // invalid
example1('SOMETHING') // valid
example1(ACTIONS.SOMETHING) // invalid

export function example2(keyOrValue:  ActionsType[keyof ActionsType]) {
    // ...
}

example2('') // valid but should not be
example2('SOMETHING') // valid
example2(ACTIONS.SOMETHING) // valid

export function example3(keyOrValue:  keyof ActionsType | ActionsType[keyof ActionsType]) {
    // ...
}

example3('') // valid but should not be
example3('SOMETHING') // valid
example3(ACTIONS.SOMETHING) // valid


// This one works, but is it possible to have this in an object?
export const SOMETHING = 'SOMETHING'
export function example4(keyOrValue: typeof SOMETHING) {
    // ...
}

example4('') // invalid
example4('SOMETHING') // valid
example4(SOMETHING) // valid
```

Is there a way to do define a type to either the key or value of an object? If so, how?

Comment: In this example, `'SOMETHING'` is both the property name and the property value; so there shouldn't be any difference between the two. In `example1(ACTIONS.SOMETHING) // invalid`, what is the actual error message?

Comment: @kaya3 TS2345 Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type '"SOMETHING"'.

Comment: Isn't the solution to make `ACTIONS` an enum? You seem to want to use it as one.

Comment: @VLAZ YES!!! That worked. Can you post a quick answer so I can accept? It's just changing the const object to an enum. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the compiler infers the `ACTIONS` object to be of type `{SOMETHING: string}`, and completely forgets about the [string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) of the `SOMETHING` property.  Then afterward, your `ActionValues` type becomes `string`, and you accept all `string` values which you don't want to do.  The compiler (reasonably) doesn't assume the value of the `SOMETHING` property will stay the same forever.  Yes, `ACTIONS` *itself* is a `const`, so you can't ever assign a new value to the `ACTIONS` variable, but its properties are still mutable, and the compiler assumes it can take any `string` value.

If you'd like the compiler to consider that `ACTIONS` is essentially immutable and that it should infer the narrowest possible type that it can, you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions) when declaring it:

```
export const ACTIONS = {
  SOMETHING: 'SOMETHING',
} as const;
```

Now the type of `ACTIONS` is inferred as `{ readonly SOMETHING: "SOMETHING"; }`, and the rest of your code goes through as desired:

```
export type ActionsType = typeof ACTIONS
export type ActionValues = ActionsType[keyof ActionsType]
export function example(keyOrValue: ActionValues) {
  // ...
}

example('SOMETHING') // valid
example(ACTIONS.SOMETHING) // valid
example('') // error!
//      ~~
// Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type '"SOMETHING"'
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wIIGEAqBJAeQDkBlOAXjgG8BYAKDjhIIFkBRHACTyIHEAuOAHJm7Lj15CANPQC+cAIapEKdAG569UJFhwYATzDA4GBDACWqnIeOUDRiADMTuQqS3ho8e8dMWUAGoKADYArsDKlH6WaNZGANoA1sD6TiZmMahxwAC6HjrwjqHIGShwoAoAtmDBwAAUyfoEUEFhwILRgSHhqACU1PSMAPRDcAB0E3KadBXVtXUirBzcfEL9I3AAbiHmACYeVTX12PjEJGOiyxLro9vBewdz9UJrcBvAUFDQAIT0G4wAgB+gL+owwUAA5qFKsBkPA0j5hAAiJFCODmZTICDwJSocwQ5AKABGtT0EDgYAUUCqwBgHzgCJsyMu4j4qLgQA)